# Django authenticate does not register a user

Tags: python, django, authentication

Somehow, I have a user in my data base from the `django.contrib.auth.models` model which isn't being authenticated.

So we have, in the ./manage.py shell:

```
>>> django.contrib.auth.models.User.objects.filter(username='tester')[0].password

u'yolo'

>>> django.contrib.auth.models.User.objects.filter(username='tester')[0].username

u'tester'
```

but:

```
>>> should_be_tester = django.contrib.auth.authenticate(username='tester',password='yolo')
```

returns nothing.  Is there something that needs to be done to the users before django will authenticate them?  I think I created these using `objects.create()`.

Comment: (this is in response to a comment that no longer exists) I'm using exactly this line from the docs:
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
with a user that's definitely in the database, but should_be_tester is none.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks as though your password is stored as clear text in the database. Try using the `set_password` method so that the password is run through the proper hashing algorithm.

When you call the `authenticate` method Django is running `yolo` through a hashing algorithm which produces a password that looks something like so: `jRQarGxWd7ZV$+npDSC0ffIXAOUo/R5KSaPFbauQdTV5eAOmkq1P/p/Y=` and then comparing the hashed value to what is stored in the database, in your case a plain text version of `yolo`. Since you are storing the password in plain text the values don't match and `None` is returned.

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

>>> u = User.objects.get(username='tester')
>>> u.set_password('yolo')
>>> u.save()

>>> should_be_tester = authenticate(username='tester', password='yolo')
>>> print(should_be_tester)
tester
```

Additional note. When you are wanting to retrieve one and only one record from the database use the `.get()` method instead of `.filter()[0]`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense!